# How to send data from RightViewController to MainView Controller in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, mmdrawercontroller

[image]

Hello, I am using `MMDrawerController` for right side menu. I have 2 `ViewController` First is `HomeVC` with Product Listing data in `UICollectionView` and there's 1 filter button.

When i press that filter button I push to filter screen `RightViewVC`. Now what I want is, I want to pass that selected filter values to `HomeVC`. How can I do this?

Comment: Delegate or Closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by multiple way

**1. By using Block Method**

When you push to `RightViewVC` write below code.

```
let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RightViewVC") as! RightViewVC
nextViewController.delegate = self as! customeDelegate
nextViewController.onApplyFilterTap = {(_ arrSelectedFilter: NSMutableArray) -> Void in
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
self.show(nextViewController, sender: self)
```

Define this in `RightViewVC` controller. I created array you can change it as per your requirement.

```
var onApplyFilterTap: ((_ arrSelectedFilter: NSMutableArray) -> Void)? = nil
```

You need to call like this

```
self.arrFilterSelection.add(whichButtonClicked)
self.arrFilterSelection.add(locationTextView.text!)
self.arrFilterSelection.add(byPriceToTextField.text!)
self.arrFilterSelection.add(byPriceFromTextField.text!)
self.arrFilterSelection.add(timeTextview.text!)

onApplyFilterTap!(self.arrFilterSelection)
```

**2. By using NotificationCenter**

Write below in your `HomeVC`

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(refreshProductListBasedonSelectedFilterValue(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "refreshProductListBasedonSelectedFilterValue"), object: nil)


@objc func refreshProductListBasedonSelectedFilterValue(_ notification: Notification) {
    let info = notification.object as? NSDictionary

    let arrSelectedFilteredValues = info?.value(forKey: "selectedFilter") as! NSMutableArray
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

From `RightViewVC` you need to call like this.

```
let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
dict.setValue(self.arrFilterSelection, forKey: "selectedFilter")
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("refreshProductListBasedonSelectedFilterValue"), object: dict)
```

**3. You can also use delegate**

Comment: Okay.Sir. Thank you for the guidance

Comment: Checking it sir. have some questions.. can you come to the chatbox?

Comment: Avoid using NSMutableArray, NSMutableDictionary in swift language